# ifort for ubuntu

Tags: intel

Actually, I have installed the ifort  in the location    '' "/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/bin/intel64 "" .  So now  what command  I will use to compile the program.  I have attached the screenshot. Please help me

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Quote from https://climserv.ipsl.polytechnique.fr/documentation/intel-ifc/Getting_Started.htm#Configuring%20the%20C++%20Compiler : " You need to also run the compiler environment script file (ifortvars.sh) that sets the environment variables."